# HTML snippet returned in $.ajax can't be traversed

Tags: jquery, ajax, code-snippets

I have a html snippet like this:

```
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
<p>Euismod tollam impedit</p>
```

When I fetch it via jQuery's ajax() method like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'mocks/test.html',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(results) {
    console.log($(results).find('p').text());
    }
});
```

I see in console this: (an empty string)

However, if I add a div around my snippet like this:

```
<div>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
    <p>Euismod tollam impedit</p>
</div>
```

Then console shows content of p element. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're building a jQuery object with two elements; the `h1` and the `p`. `find()` searches the descendants of the elements in the jQuery object, but your `p` **is part of** the jQuery object.

You need to use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) instead in this circumstance, which looks *within* the elements in the jQuery object.

```
alert($(results).filter('p').text());
```

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML snippet produces a pair of elements in a single jQuery object and `.find()` will only search their *descendant nodes*.

You either have to enclose them in a container (such that you get one element in the jQuery object with two descendents, as you found), or use `.filter()` instead.